# Error in summation of pivot table

Tags: excel

This is extracted from my pivot table:-

[image]

For some reasons, the summation for column H, I, J & K are completely wrong.

Column H shd be 1,012, column I 453.75.

Column A to G is based on a set of data.

As for Column H:-

[image]

Column G:-

[image]

Column I & J:-

[image]

[image]

Pls help !!!

Thanks

Comment: I don't know, but I see that both amounts are 31 times what they should be, and there are 31 dates/rows.

Comment: Yes, there are 31 rows but it doesn't make sense that the total of column H multiplied 31. Something must hv gone wrong some where.

Answer (score 0):

I knew there was something familiar about this error, but until you edited your question to reveal you're using calculated fields, I couldn't think what.

At any rate, this is a problem with calculated fields, and one of the reasons that I avoid them whenever possible. What's happening in your total is that it's totaling the Rate,i.e., adding it together 31 times and multiplying that by the total Normal. So, instead of 5.5 * Normal, for the total you get (5.5 * 31) * Normal.

The solution, and what I consider a best practice, is to move these kinds of calculations to your source data. In other words, calculate Normal Wage, OTIS Wage, etc. in the source data, and then pivot on that.